# nginx - run shell/python script on wget request

Tags: http, nginx, server, wget

I want to run a shell/python script on each wget to my nginx server.

For example, if I do wget http:///text.txt?example=100

I want to call a script that generates a new file called text100.txt, and returns it.

In other words, can I pass the GET params to the script, and return arbitrary files from that script so the wget client will download them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking about is called [cgi-bin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface).

However, I wouldn't recommend using it;

- I would recommend against using shell scripts for web serving altogether, and
- for Python I'd suggest one of the web micro-frameworks such as [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I saw that cgi returns the standard output. In that case, how can I return the files' contents from the script?

Comment: In a shell script, you can use `cat`; however, you're more likely than not to end up with a security hole. In python, you can use `print()` or `sys.stdout.write()`. Again, though, much better to use a modern web framework; cgi-bin is now pretty much only of historical interest.